# Finding the determinant of a $3\times 3 $ matrix with row vectors of the form $[ak\quad a^2+k^2\quad 1]$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am currently solving the matrix (I need to find determinant):

\begin{bmatrix}
    ab & a^2 + b^2 & 1 \\[0.3em]
    ac & a^2 + c^2 & 1 \\[0.3em]
    ad & a^2 + d^2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

I got down to the equation:

$a(cd^2 - c^2d + bd^2 - b^2d +bc^2 - b^2c)$

I know that the answer is $a(b-d)(c-d)(c-b)$, however I have hard time getting there. It seems that I am missing some simplification trick or something.

I already tried factoring out some of the variables but did not progressed much.

Could you give me a hint how should I approach such an expression?

Comment: Note that the determinant is a polynomial of degree $4$ in variables $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.  Let $p(a,b,c,d)$ be this polynomial.  If $a=0$, then the first column is $0$, making the determinant $0$.  Thus, $a$ divides $p(a,b,c,d)$.  If two of the variables $b$, $c$, and $d$ are equal, then the matrix has two equal rows, whence the determinant is $0$.  Hence, $b-c$, $c-d$, and $d-b$ divide $p(a,b,c,d)$.  Thus, $$p(a,b,c,d)=ka(b-c)(c-d)(d-b)$$ for some constant $k$.  Since $$2k=p(1,1,-1,0)=2\,,$$ we get $k=1$, so $$p(a,b,c,d)=a(b-c)(c-d)(d-b)$$ is the determinant of the required matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
    ab & a^2 + b^2 & 1 \\[0.3em]
    ac & a^2 + c^2 & 1 \\[0.3em]
    ad & a^2 + d^2 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = a \det\begin{bmatrix}
    b & a^2 + b^2 & 1 \\[0.3em]
    c-b & c^2 - b^2 & 0 \\[0.3em]
    d-b & d^2 - b^2 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$
$$=a(c-b)(d-b) \det\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & c+ b\\[0.3em]
    1 & d+b
\end{bmatrix} = a (c-b)(d-b)(d-c)$$

Comment: Looks great! 
I was able to follow your steps. 

The only thing is weird to me is that the answer has $c - d$ and on this solution we have $d - c$

Comment: There are two differences with flipped variables. You have
$$a(c-b)(d-b)(d-c)=a(c-b)(b-d)(c-d)$$

Comment: Now I get it! 
Thanks! I got that solution now.

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that your factorized formula is incorrect. In fact, it must have a factor $a$, i.e.,
$$
\det(A)=-a\cdot (b - c)(b - d)(c - d).
$$
Your formula doesn't depend on $a$ at all. *Edit* You have corrected it.

The formula then follows from 
$$
(b-c)(b-d)(c-d)=
b^2c - b^2d - bc^2 + bd^2 + c^2d - cd^2$$
what you had already, by grouping terms with $b-c$, namely $(b-c)(bc-dc-bd-d^2).$